Excel autofill date when data entered in a nested worksheet
I took this existing code which works fine in a single sheet to update the date when data is entered in adjacent cell E it updates with the new date in Col D, and it updates daily in a test sheet when data is entered in Col D the new date is updated in Col E.
Where I have an issue is where I have taken an excel copy and paste from a different excel document and copied it into the existing excel sheet. So it is essentially a nested excel document embedded in this excel page. And in this sheet I have values which I will be changing like percent from 0-100%. In the embedded excel copy and paste sheet I have this macro below for the sheet, for column D in the embedded sheet I actually have a simple formula with "=" and I use the regular non embedded sheet and select a cell with the percent value. This works fine when i update the cell with the percent value to a different value daily I can see the percent in the Embedded sheet column D update when I double click the embedded sheet and it opens it updates the percent just fine. What it does not update however is the date. The date remains static and never updates. I'm not sure why the date does not update but the percent does, it is almost as if it is ignoring the macro after the first time it populate a date. This same macro is a regular sheet as I stated works fine and updates the date.
Any help is appreciated.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("E:E")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            r.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "m/dd/yy"
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Updated the code and no luck
